# Event is undefined in Firefox during dojo.connect onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, dom-events, onkeypress

I have the following declarative js/dojo code running properly in Chrome:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="onKeyPress">
        console.log(event);
    </script>
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/pfSXF/)

Typing some characters into the `TextBox` I get some `KeyboardEvents` in console output.

Exactly the same code doesn't run in Firefox. I get the following error in console output:

> event is not defined

Fetching the object from `window` doesn't work either (same error output):

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="onKeyPress">
        if(!event) {
            event = window.event;
        }

        console.log(event);
    </script>
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/pfSXF/1/)

What is the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declarative dojo code prevents Firefox from passing the `event` object to the connected function - one has to do that by hand via `args` attribute:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="onKeyPress" args="event">
        console.log(event);
    </script>
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/pfSXF/2/)